# Wordpress перестал применять изменения в файлах

Tags: php, wordpress

Я редактирую, например footer.php, но на сайте ничего не видно. Я решил установить плагин File manager и в нем видно, что файл редактировался. Потом, через неопредленное количество времени или каких-то моих действий, изменения вдруг срабатывают. В может быть проблема? Использую winscp, но так же решил попробовать и в filezilla - результат тот же

Comment: Плагинов кэширования нет на сайте?

Comment: нет, нету таких

Comment: Кто-то из админов поставил плагин WP Super Cache. Как оказалось, спасибо за наводку, отключил. Сколько нервов и времени потрачено зря...